# PHP weird datetime difference 180 minutes instead of 240

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

When I run this code on my Windows 10 WSL with php 7.1.18 installed:

```
$start = new DateTime("2018-03-24 00:00:00");
$end = new DateTime("2018-03-24 04:00:00");
$minutes = ($end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp()) / 60;
echo $start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$end->format("Y-m-d H:i:d")." minutes: ".$minutes."\n";

$start = new DateTime("2018-03-25 00:00:00");
$end = new DateTime("2018-03-25 04:00:00");
$minutes = ($end->getTimestamp() - $start->getTimestamp()) / 60;
echo $start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$end->format("Y-m-d H:i:d")." minutes: ".$minutes."\n";
```

I get the following results:

```
2018-03-24 00:00:00 - 2018-03-24 04:00:24 minutes: 240
2018-03-25 00:00:00 - 2018-03-25 04:00:25 minutes: 180
```

The bottom line should also be 240 minutes?

If I run it on our production server, I get the same results. If I run it on some online code testers like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/,  It returns 240 both times correctly.

Must be some weird localization error or something? Why would it be ok on the 24th but not on the 25th?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because daylight savings starts on the 25th.

4hours - 1 hour for GMT-1 = 10800 seconds / 60 = 180

To fix the issue, always use UTC:

`date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

- With: https://3v4l.org/SXNW3
- Without: https://3v4l.org/TkRDh

Comment: Sidenote, be careful of the `H:i:d` it should be `H:i:s`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the d was a late-night typo.  Its interesting because I’m calculating how long an employee has been working.  Technically he has only worked 3 hours during that shift since there is a non-existing hour.  Wonder how HR thinks about this one.

Comment: @OscarGala Technically it's not time travel but sometimes feels like it, always use UTC, then offset to the local users time. In accounting 4 hours is 4 hours, if you rely on BST for your dates the issue happens. Same for booking systems store in UTC then display local users time, then its correct.

Comment: In this case it shouldn’t be 4 hours. It’s really 3 hours.  If you send someone over to a customer to help them and they get 3 hours of help, but have to pay for 4 just because it happened during the daylight savings time, I don’t think they would agree with your way of accounting.  I don’t think the accountant would agree on the other side when the clock goes back an hour and you deliver 4 hours of work, but charge only 3